# Find the score of a scrabble word in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am having a letter mapped with its respective score

```
dict = fromList([("A",1), ("B",3), ("C", 3), ("E", 1), ("D", 2), ("G", 2), ("F", 4), ("I", 1), ("H", 4), ("K", 5), ("J", 8), ("M", 3), ("L", 1), ("O", 1), ("N", 1), ("Q", 10), ("P", 3), ("S", 1), ("R", 1), ("U", 1), ("T", 1), ("W", 4), ("V", 4), ("Y", 4), ("X", 8), ("Z", 10)])
```

If the main send a word to the function the function should return the score with respect to the dict and the letters in the word.

EX:- Main :- APPLE
Function should return :- 9

```
(A Score)1+(P Score)3 +(P Score)3 + (L Score) 1+(E Score)1 = 9
```

Comment: What's your question? If you want help with your code you have to post it.

Comment: This site is not a problem/homework solving service. You should post your attempt at a solution, so that we can comment on it and prod you on the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
main = print $ calWordScore "APPLE"

calcWordScore :: String -> Int
calcWordScore word = sum $ map calcLetterScore word

calcLetterScore :: Char -> Int
calcLetterScore ch = Map.fromList([('A',1), ('B',3), ('C', 3), ('E', 1), ('D', 2), ('G', 2), ('F', 4), ('I', 1), ('H', 4), ('K', 5), ('J', 8), ('M', 3), ('L', 1), ('O', 1), ('N', 1), ('Q', 10), ('P', 3), ('S', 1), ('R', 1), ('U', 1), ('T', 1), ('W', 4), ('V', 4), ('Y', 4), ('X', 8), ('Z', 10)]) Map.! ch
```

And you need to 
    import qualified Data.Map.Lazy as Map

Answer (score 4):

You could use `lookup` to create a function that maps keys to values:

```
mapper :: Eq k => [(k, v)] -> k -> v
mapper dict k = case lookup k dict of Nothing  -> undefined
                                      (Just v) -> v

scrabble :: Char -> Int
scrabble = mapper [ ('A', 1)
                  , ('B', 3)
                  , ('C', 3)
                  , ('E', 1)
                  , ('D', 2)
                  , ('G', 2)
                  , ('F', 4)
                  , ('I', 1)
                  , ('H', 4)
                  , ('K', 5)
                  , ('J', 8)
                  , ('M', 3)
                  , ('L', 1)
                  , ('O', 1)
                  , ('N', 1)
                  , ('Q', 10)
                  , ('P', 3)
                  , ('S', 1)
                  , ('R', 1)
                  , ('U', 1)
                  , ('T', 1)
                  , ('W', 4)
                  , ('V', 4)
                  , ('Y', 4)
                  , ('X', 8)
                  , ('Z', 10)
                  ]
```

Now all you need to do is create a function which takes a string and returns its score:

```
score :: String -> Int
score = sum . map scrabble

main = print $ score "APPLE"
```

That's all.

**Edit:** There's nothing wrong with returning `undefined` in `mapper` when a lookup fails. If you need error handling you could simply define `mapper` as `flip lookup` and hey presto `scrabble` is now of type `Char -> Maybe Int`.

Consider how you would write `scrabble` using pattern matching:

```
scrabble :: Char -> Int
scrabble 'A' = 1
scrabble 'B' = 3
scrabble 'C' = 3
scrabble 'D' = 2
scrabble 'E' = 1
scrabble 'F' = 4
scrabble 'G' = 2
scrabble 'H' = 4
scrabble 'I' = 1
scrabble 'J' = 8
scrabble 'K' = 5
scrabble 'L' = 1
scrabble 'M' = 3
scrabble 'N' = 1
scrabble 'O' = 1
scrabble 'P' = 3
scrabble 'Q' = 10
scrabble 'R' = 1
scrabble 'S' = 1
scrabble 'T' = 1
scrabble 'U' = 1
scrabble 'V' = 4
scrabble 'W' = 4
scrabble 'X' = 8
scrabble 'Y' = 4
scrabble 'Z' = 10
```

If the pattern match fails then you end up with a bottom value anyway. This is not a problem if you know that the pattern match will never fail. If you do need to handle failures then simply use `flip lookup` as I mentioned above.

Comment: Ouch, `undefined`! And not one comment about using it?

Comment: I don't see how that's a problem. It's pessimistic to always want to account for the context of a possible failure. Sometimes it's better to be optimistic and say "screw you" to possible failures - especially if you're sure that your code won't be used by other people and you know that you won't ever get into a bad state. Anyway, I updated my answer and addressed the problem.

Comment: I should have been more specific. I didn't mean to say undefined has no place (especially in personal code) but that it probably almost always warrants a comment here on SO, especially if you're unsure of the qualifications of the asker. Anyway, your comment resolves this. :)